# Replacing all occurrences of a substring in a string without using regex

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge

[Problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p192570) Statement:

> Given two strings, base and remove, return a version of the base
>   string where all instances of the remove string have been removed (not
>   case sensitive). You may assume that the remove string is length 1 or
>   more. Remove only non-overlapping instances, so with "xxx" removing
>   "xx" leaves "x".

---

**withoutString("Hello there", "llo") → "He there"**

**withoutString("Hello there", "e") → "Hllo thr"**

**withoutString("Hello there", "x") → "Hello there"**

Please feel free to review the code below:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
   final int rLen = remove.length();
   final int bLen = base.length();
   String op      = "";

   for(int i = 0; i < bLen;)
   {
        if( !(i + rLen > bLen) && base.substring(i, i + rLen).equalsIgnoreCase(remove) )
        {
            i += rLen;
            continue;
        }
        op += base.substring(i, i + 1);
        i++;
   }

   return op;   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `StringBuilder` should always be your preferred choice when doing String manipulation. It does not always make sense, but almost always.

Additionally, indexOf takes a 'from' location, and it makes the whole thing easier.... Convert both inputs to lower-case, then do the matching using the lower-case versions, but the substrings using the unknown-case.

The complicated assign-in-where-condition logic makes the loop conditions easier, but you do need to understand what this does:

```
while ((find = lcbase.indexOf(lcremove, previous)) >= 0) {
```

it searches for thelower-case remove from the previous position, saves the value to find, and checks that the result is 'positive'.... all in the condition of a while loop.

The full code is:

```
public static String withoutString(String base, String remove) {

    final String lcbase = base.toLowerCase();
    final String lcremove = remove.toLowerCase();
    int find = 0;
    int previous = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base.length());
    while ((find = lcbase.indexOf(lcremove, previous)) >= 0) {
        result.append(base.substring(previous, find));
        previous = find + remove.length();
    }
    result.append(base.substring(previous));
    return result.toString();

}
```

See this [running inideone](http://ideone.com/nDrnmS)